# Making a Array of random string from another array.

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to make an array of random colors from another array.

```
 String [] colors = new String[6];
         colors[0] = "red";
         colors[1] = "green";
         colors[2] = "blue";
         colors[3] = "yellow";
         colors[4] = "purple";
         colors[5] = "orange";
```

That's my array as of now. I want to make a **new** array with just 4 of those colors **without** duplicates.

So far I know how to make an array of randoms; however, I don't know how to take care of duplicates efficiently.

Comment: Add them to a `LinkedList`, and take (remove) from a random index between 0 and `size()`

Comment: You have few ways to achieve this. You can unsort a list of numbers from 0,1,2,3,4,5 and get the first 4 after the unsort. By unsort I mean shuffle them. You can randomly remove one of the elements. You can keep adding them to a Set collections, although it may take a while to finally add them all.

Comment: loop and add to a `HashSet` until the size of the `HashSet` is 4 would be by approach

Comment: I strongly suggest Knuth's shuffling algorithm, provides very good randomness for shuffling. You can pick the DataStructure of your choice to remove dups..

Comment: This question gets asked about 5 times a week -- how to make a random selection without replacement.  Please spend a little time searching for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want a Set. A Set is designed to remove duplicates.

```
Set<String> set = ...
for(String s : "a,b,c,d,e,f,d,e,c,a,b".split(","))
    set.add(s);
```

This set will have all the unique strings.

Comment: This is a completely non-Java way to program. Looks more like lisp/clojure. Get some sequences and go!

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis It uses methods from java.lang, does get more Java than that. ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
List<String> colourList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(colors));
Collections.shuffle(colourList);
return colourList.subList(0,4).toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd strongly suggest you don't use arrays for this. Add what you need to a Set and it will handle duplicate management for you. You can always convert back to an array if need be.

Answer (score 0):

You can just select random entries from `colors`, and add them into a [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) until the set has four elements:

```
Set<String> randomStrings = new HashSet<String>();
Random random = new Random();
while( randomStrings.size() < 4) {
    int index = random.nextInt( colors.length);
    randomStrings.add( colors[index]);
}
```

You can try it out in [this demo](https://ideone.com/xjndNx), where it selects four colors at random when you run it. You'll get output similar to:

```
Random colors: [orange, red, purple, blue]
```

Comment: But you have to do it without replacement.

Comment: This IS without replacement.  It's going into a `Set`.